# GNU scientific library linking

Tags: software-installation

I have installed GNU scientific library (http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) which is located in `/home/usr/gsl-1.9` and installed statistical programme in `/home/usr/statprog`

when I tried to compile it, this happens:

```
$ cd home/usr/statprog 
$ make
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/ -c -o mlRho.o mlRho.c
gcc: error: D_GNU_SOURCE: No such file or directory
make: *** [mlRho.o] Error 1
```

It says no such file or directory. How to link GNU library to this statprog?

Answer (score 2):

There's a dash (`-`) missing in the command before `D_GNU_SOURCE`. Passing `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to the compiler is equivalent to adding `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the start of the `c` file.

It looks like the `Makefile` is corrupted somehow. Try

```
find . -type f -exec grep -lZ D_GNU_SOURCE {} + |
  xargs -r0 perl -pi -e 's/-*D_GNU_SOURCE/-D_GNU_SOURCE/g'
```

and run `make` again. However it's likely that something more fundamental is wrong here for that error to have crept in in the first place.

Comment: Still it shows error. How to link GNU library to this statprog manually?